# WordPress nav_menu_link_attributes Not Working

Tags: wordpress, custom-data-attribute

I am attempting to add a data attribute to all menu items, but it's simply not working. I am using `wp_nav_menu` to call my menu walker as well.

```
function menu_anchor_attributes ( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['data-menuanchor'] = $item->attr_title;
return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_anchor_attributes', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Define "Simply Not Working".  1. Does the `data-menuanchor` attribute appear, but is empty? 2. Does NOT `data-menuanchor` attribute appear at all? 3. In order to help, we also need to know **how you are calling your menu**, so please show that code as well.

Comment: I created a new question under wordpress.se before it got bumped out: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237020/wordpress-nav-menu-link-attributes-not-working